# How to disable buddypress top mini adminbar

Tags: buddypress

I am having trouble with adminbar in my site. I have buddypress installed on my site. i have disabled wordpress default admin bar using few lines of code. But it still showing i am pretty sure its coming from buddypress. is there any simeple lines of code that can remove top admin bar? I don't want to use plugin.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this code in config.php

This file is located in the root directory.

```
** THis Will Remove disgusting Buddypress Top Admin Bar. Add this line of code at last of the previous codes and you are done */

define( 'BP_DISABLE_ADMIN_BAR', true );
```